# some questions about super() method in Java

Tags: java, super

In the book "Effective Java",I can't understand the result when I run the following code.

```
public class InstrumentHashSet<E> extends HashSet<E>{

      private int count;
      @Override
      public boolean add(E e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          count++;
          return super.add(e);
      }
      @Override
      public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          int size = c.size();
          count+= size;
          return super.addAll(c);
      }

      public int getCount(){
          return count;
      }
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          InstrumentHashSet<String> s = new InstrumentHashSet<String>();
          s.addAll(Arrays.asList("xinwa1","xinwa2","xinwa3"));
          System.out.println("hashSet count:"+s.getCount());
      }
}
```

I can't understand why the result is six. I know that the addAll() method in parent class calls the add() method. But there is no 'count++' in add() method in parent class. I initially thinK that subclass overrides the add() method,so the super().addAll() calls the add() method in subclass. But when run the following code,I'm confused.

```
class Point {
      public int x;
      public int y;

      public Point(int x,int y) {
           this.x= x;
           this.y= y;
      }

      public void method() {
           System.out.println("this is parent");
      }

}

public class ColorPoint extends Point{

      public ColorPoint(int x, int y) {
           super(x, y);
      }

      @Override
      public void method() {
           System.out.println("this is son");
      }

      public void print() {
           super.method();
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
           ColorPoint c = new ColorPoint(1, 2);
           c.print();

      }
}
```

Why the result is 'this is parent'? According to the example in 'Effective Java', I think the result should be 'this is son'. Please tell me what's wrong with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I initially thinK that subclass overrides the add() method,so the super().addAll() calls the add() method in subclass. But when run the following code,I'm confused.

-- You are Correct

### In ColorPoint, In print you are explicitly making a call to parents method and hence it results in "this is parent". When you use super.someMethod() you explicitly telling to call parents method irrespective whether it is ovveriden by child or not

When it will override and print "this is son", below code will print "this is son"

```
class Point {
public int x;
public int y;

public Point(int x,int y) {
    this.x= x;
    this.y= y;
}


public void method() {
    System.out.println("this is parent");
}

}

public void print() {
    method();
}

public class ColorPoint extends Point{

public ColorPoint(int x, int y) {
    super(x, y);
}


@Override
public void method() {
    System.out.println("this is son");
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    ColorPoint c = new ColorPoint(1, 2);
    c.print();

}
}
```

## Changes In Above Code:

1. Move print method to parent and remove from Colorpoint
2. inside print change super.method() to method()

## Explanation:

```
You are using object which is instance of ColorPoint, all methods
will be called from ColorPoint class implemenation, if any method is
not present it will call parents method.

When you call print on ColorPoint, it is not present in ColorPoint,
so call print() in method(but you are still using ColorPoint
instance).

Now print calls method, it is present in ColorPoint, so call method
in ColorPoint and not parent.

Whenever you call method like super.method() then it will always try
to call method from super
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I almost understand. Your example is very great. :)

Comment: I actually feel  you haven't answered the question at all.  How does your analysis relate to `InstrumentHashSet` and `HashSet`?  Why does `count` end up being 6, not 3?  I'm actually surprised that kdk0108 has accepted this answer, instead of one of the three answers that actually deal with this issue.

Comment: The actual question was in last two lines I.e.,

Why the result is 'this is parent'? According to the example in 'Effective Java', I think the result should be 'this is son'. Please tell me what's wrong with me.

Comment: @Dawood ibn Kareem,you don't understand my confusion, I know that addAll() calls add() internally, I can't understand why super.addAll() calls add() of the subclass,but the super.method() in ColorPoint class doesn't call method() which is overrided by the subclass.JTeam's answer let me understand where my mind is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Below is java implementation of addAll() method. As seen here, it calls add() internally. So, you should increment your count in add() method alone.

```
public boolean More ...addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
       boolean modified = false;
        Iterator<? extends E> e = c.iterator();
        while (e.hasNext()) {
            if (add(e.next()))
                modified = true;
        }
        return modified;
   }
```

So, when you call addAll() with a collection of 3 elements, count is increment immediately to 3 and then it increments by 1 each time your add() method is called.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't understand why the result is six.

When you invoke  `super.addAll(c)`, you invoke the `addAll()` method of the super class.

And `addAll()` in `HashSet` uses the implementation defined in `AbstractCollection` that iterates on the collection in parameter and invokes  `add()` on each element :

```
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    boolean modified = false;
    for (E e : c)
        if (add(e))
            modified = true;
    return modified;
}
```

So this code performs twice the incrementation :

```
@Override
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int size = c.size();
    count+= size; // + 3
    return super.addAll(c); // + 3
}
```

Here :

```
 count+= size; // + 3
```

and here :

```
 return super.addAll(c); // + 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The key point is **polymorphism**.  Often, there are two versions of a method, with the same signature, but in two different classes, and both versions are accessible to code that's running.  The JVM has  to decide which one to call, it bases its decision on the actual **class** of the object - not on the type of the variable that references the object, and not on which class it's currently running code from.

In other words if `x` is a variable that refers to an `InstrumentHashSet` and you call `x.add(something)`, it's the `add` method in the `InstrumentHashSet` class that gets called.

In your example, when you call `super.addAll`, this calls `addAll` in the `HashSet` class, which in turn calls `add` once for each object that's being added.  But because your object is an `InstrumentHashSet`, it's the `InstrumentHashSet` version of the `add` method that gets called.

So your code runs `count += size;` (which sets `count` to 3) then makes three calls to your `add` method, each of which increments `count`.  The end result is that `count` is 6.

Comment: OK, @kdk0108,  "almost understand" isn't good enough for me.  So I've added a couple of paragraphs in an attempt to make it clearer.  Please comment again if you still don't understand.

Comment: Haha, I didn't click the save button till just now.